# ¿Cómo extraer una fila de un Datagridview a un Array? C#

Tags: c#, array, datagrid

Cómo puedo extraer una fila en específico de un `Datagridview` y mandarla a un `Array`.  Les dejo cual es la fila que necesito guardar en mi `Array`.[image: Es la fila que necesito guardar]
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando las extensiones de `linq` es muy simple.

```
int[] llegada = DataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                               .Select(r=> Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells["llegada"].Value))
                               .ToArray();
```

Cuando use Cells["llegada"] deberías poner el nombre de la columna del grid, use "llegada" porque imagine ese sería el nombre, pero reemplazalo por el correcto que definas, sino puedes usar el index de la columna Cells[1]

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio a la perfeccion.